# Calling https service in Postman client after providing auth credentials in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, postman, self-signed

I'm testing a REST service provided by a vendor and I'm using Postman client. Initially if I tried to make service call with necessary authorization headers, the client spits out a response (not from the service but Postman) where it says something similar to cannot get a response. But once I attempt the same GET request through Chrome, a username and password is prompted from the browser and once I provide that the JSON response is shown in browser screen.

Once that is done , when I attempt the same request or other request from Postman it works fine and gives me response JSON from service.

Could someone please help me understand what happens here, thanks.

Comment: obviously: something is missing in Postman try something to catch your requests, and compare it then, f.e. fiddler .

Comment: Did you tried to see the postman connection on the postman console? If you don’t know how I can post this in the answer.

Comment: Hi all thanks for your help. I wasn't updated about the latest Postman client, not the Chrome extension. In it there is a way to skip certificate check. Once that is done it works.